# How to bound probability density functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, upper-lower-bounds

For a random variable $X$ with PDF $p(x)$, my goal is to give a convergence rate to 
$$
\int_\epsilon^{2\epsilon}p(x)dx\overset{\epsilon\to 0}{\to} 0
$$
Note that this is not always the case; e.g. $p(x) = \delta(x)$.

My approach is, find $B$ where $p(x) < B$ for all $x$. Then, this quantity is certainly upper bounded by $B\epsilon$. However, $p(x)$ is super hard to characterize ($X$ is like the sum and product of a lot of things).

1) Are there nice techniques out there used to bound the PDF value of complicated random variables? I feel like with sums I can do something with convolution, but products I'm completely lost.

2) Are there better ways of approaching this goal? I feel like an exponential bound would be excellent, rather than a linear bound. It doesn't quite feel like a concentration inequality would work well here, though.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Edit: Some progress I made. Consider $A$ and $B$ independent random variables, and $C = f(A,B)$. Define $p_A$, $p_B$, $p_C$ the PDFs of $A$, $B$, and $C$, and for any random variable $X$, $p_X^\infty$ the max PDF value. Then
$$
p_C(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty p_{C|A}(f(A,B) | a) p_A(a) da \overset{(a)}{=}\int_{-\infty}^\infty p_{C|A}(f(A,B)) p_A(a) da\leq p_{C|A}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty  p_A(a) = p_{C|A}^\infty 
$$
So, for example, if  $C = (A+B)/2$, then $p_{C|A}^\infty = p_{B/2}^\infty$. Taking $A$ and $B$ Gaussian $\mathcal N(0,1)$, then we can get stuff like
$$
p_{A}^\infty = p_B^\infty = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \Rightarrow p_{B/2}^\infty = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \leq p_C^\infty 
$$
This is consistent with what we know about Gaussian random variable behavior.

In other words, if $f$ is a reasonable mixture of independent random variables all with "non-peaky" PDFs, then the PDF of $f$ cannot be peaky.

*However*, none of this holds if $A$ and $B$ are dependent (step (a) is key). This is now my main challenge; how can we get around this?

Comment: $p(x)=\delta (x)$ doesn't make sense. $\delta$ measures have no densities.

Comment: Well, it's a PMF, right? Anyway that example isn't too important since I think the limit is still 0 (which is never achieved.) The issue is more the convergence guarantee itself. Take instead $p(x) = e^{-x+A}$ where the $A$ is just for normalization. Then the convergence is not even linear.

Comment: Overall, I have some silly / simple ways of answering this question, but mostly I'm wondering if people have worked on this type of problem before, and have standard techniques that might be more powerful (e.g. concentration inequalities, or something related.)

Comment: If by $\delta$ measure you mean a discrete distribution, they indeed have densities - with respect to counting measure.

Comment: Hmm... Ok so the reason I think that this $\delta$ is necessary is that when I'm actually simulating my stuff, I get a huge peak at 0. (Makes sense for my problem, nothing weird.) I never see peaks away from 0, but given that I know at least one appears, I feel like I need to bound everything else to not have peaks. In other words, if I choose any $\epsilon$, how can I be sure there is no $\delta(\epsilon/2)$ in my distribution?

Comment: Maybe more concretely, I made some progress: if I'm looking at the PDF of $f(X,Y)$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then (maybe, still ironing out details) the max PDF value of $f$ is at most the min of the max of the PDFs  of $X$ and $Y$. So if $Y$ is Gaussian, then I know at most the max value of the PDF of $f$ is like $1/\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}$. BUT when $X$ and $Y$ are correlated, it might not (and does not in my scenario) happen that way.

Comment: Ask on the chem and physics stackexchanges.